# Text messages won't delete and message app freezes

Tags: iphone, ios

iPhone 6 with ios8. After months of normal operation, suddenly now I cannot delete either a single text or an entire conversation.  When I try, the message or conversation appears to be gone, but the app then freezes and I cannot access any other text conversation. Eventually I get a blank text screen as though there are no conversations at all.  After a power off/power on, all conversations are back, including those which I deleted.  I have scoured the web for a solution and tried the various suggested remedies.  Nothing works.  Has anyone else encountered this issue and found a solution?

Comment: I suggest a factory restore: back up your phone to iCloud (or iTunes or both), and then wipe and restore it.